# How to add js snippet with undefined number of placeholders on sublime

Tags: javascript, arrays, bash, sublimetext3, code-snippets

I'm trying to add a snippet that receives N arguments and tabs through all of them.
The first argument($1) is the name of the variable:

```
var $1 =
```

and the rest of the arguments fill the array.

```
['$2','$3','$#'];
```

Now the tricky part is this, I don't know how many args will go inside the array. Is there a way to tell how many placeholders I'll need so I can tab through and type them in sequence? Can I use for loops when defining snippets?

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[ var $1 = ['$@']; ]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>array</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
    <description>Create an array</description>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, the following [substring expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) technique applied on positional parameters will get all the arguments starting from the second to the last one:

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${@:2}"
```

Calling script.sh:

```
bash script.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've got an ugly but working solution which is declaring multiple snippets instead, each for a different number of items.

That translates to:

```
<tabTrigger>var1</tabTrigger>
<content><![CDATA[ var $1 = ['$2']; ]]></content>

<tabTrigger>var2</tabTrigger>
<content><![CDATA[ var $1 = ['$2','$3']; ]]></content>

<tabTrigger>varN</tabTrigger>
<content><![CDATA[ var $1 = ['$N+1']; ]]></content>
```

You can define N number of snippets  with N+1 place holders.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[ var $1 = ['$2']; ]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>var1</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
    <description>Create an array</description>
</snippet>
```

How would you improve this? 
Is there a different way to do it?

Please, share your thoughts.